# Can I track permission set assignment with sfdx or other tools like gearset?

Tags: salesforce

I am investigating if it is at all possible to track assigned permission sets, profiles and roles with the sfdx cli tools. So far my findings are that Permission sets and Profiles are trackable as they get converted to source but it is up to the administrator to assign profiles / permission sets after deployment.
Can anyone confirm this and point me to some documentation on the limits of what the sfdx cli can pull.

Answer (score 0):

There's https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm but that's not exactly what are you asking, the question is bit confusing.

PermissionSetAssignment table is well, a table. Normal data like Account, not metadata. Same with Users, their Roles, group memberships... You wouldn't typically store it in version control unless you're after some "golden copy" good test dataset to load to sandboxes/scratch orgs.

SF tried once to be smart with deploying queue memberships, record folder permissions and approval process assignees and the results are... Meh. You inspect the XML file and see usernames with sandbox suffix in them that they try to magically match during deployment to target org. It's "fun" when developer who created the report folder doesn't exist in production / username doesn't match (creator automatically gets added as Manager, it's extra step to remember and maybe remove that). It's even more "fun" when you keep working on the project in different sandboxes and git keeps reporting changes of suffix from ".dev" to ".proto" or ".hotfix"...

Try to rethink your question, what are you after? You can implement single sign on with piece of apex code running on login (or look into Identity Connect) so people's permissions will be synced based on their role in Active Directory/Google apps engine / what have you. Or if you really want you should be able to periodically query & upsert back CSV of PermissionSetAssignments. Or have a script during deployment to run a bunch of permset assign commands?

What will you do when John Doe moves from Marketing department to Sales? Who's right, SF or git project? Would it really need a deployment to change it?